# Sass mixin not being imported or compiled

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I'm using webpack 4 and the mini-css-extract-plugin along with sass-loader / node-sass to compile my sass into css. Everything seems to be working fine, however a mixin that is located in an imported scss file will not work and I get a build error.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-1!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--6-2!./src/sass/components.scss
Module build failed:
  @include radi(10px);
          ^
      No mixin named radi
      in /Users/Me/Sites/project/src/sass/components.scss (line 15, column 12)
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-1!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--6-2!./src/css/core.css 6:10-150
```

The weird thing is if I move that mixin into the scss file that is referencing it then it works and compiles. The order of the imported scss files was the first place I looked but the mixins are loaded before the call to it, so I'm really confused why this keeps failing :(

contents of mixins.scss

```
@mixin radi($radius) {
   -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
   -moz-border-radius: $radius;
   -ms-border-radius: $radius;
   border-radius: $radius;
};
```

contents of components.scss

```
.box {
   width: 100px;
   @include radi(10px);
   background-color: pink;
}
```

Then I have a core.css file that imports all my scss files

```
@import url("../vendor/normalize.css");
@import url("../vendor/grid.scss");
@import url("../vendor/fonts.css")
@import url("../sass/mixins.scss");
@import url("../sass/components.scss");
```

As you can see mixins gets loaded before components so the mixin should be available to components.scss, however it isn't. As I mentioned before if I put the mixin into components.scss where the call to the mixin exists then the mixin works! confusing! Even if I put an import statement into to top of the components.scss to load the mixin file it still fails :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When importing files you must be aware of those rules:

- if you want to import a scss file you just need to reference its location and file name; no need for extension: `@import “path/to/scssfile”;`
- if you want to import a css, you point to the css file including its file extension using `url()`: `@import url(“path/to/cssfile.css”);`
- but if you use an `url()` to import a scss file, then the file will be compiled and added as a simple css import, so `@import url(“path/to/scssfile”);` will compile the scss file and add an import to its css output file

So the solution is to remove the `url()` of your imported scss files:

```
@import url("../vendor/normalize.css");
@import "../vendor/grid";
@import url("../vendor/fonts.css")
@import "../sass/mixins";
@import "../sass/components";
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This might just be a typo in your code above but you are missing a `;` after the `import` of `fonts.css`? Maybe that will help..